# edgesIgnoringSafeArea on TabView with PageTabViewStyle not working

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios14

Using a TabView as a pageviewer by using `.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())` works fine, but trying to let it run from edge to edge by applying `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` does not seem to work.

What am I missing here?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .green, .blue]
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(0...2, id: \.self) { index in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(colors[index])
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

[image: TabView + PageTabViewStyle + edgesIgnoringSafeArea]

Adding another  `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` to the `Rectangle` or `ForEach` also doen't work.

Note that all these questions are different because they **do not** use use `PageTabViewStyle()`:

- [How do I use a TabView with a NavigationView in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57965447)
- [Adding a TabView makes the Navigation Bar not cover the safe area in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173696)
- [NavigationView doesn't display correctly when using TabView in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779387)
- [In my NavigationView '.edgesIgnoringSafeArea' does not move content past the safe area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60136913)

Their solution (adding `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)`) doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12.2 beta 3

Answer (score 38):

1. Remove .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) from the TabView
2. Add frame to the TabView with screen width and height
3. Wrap a TabView with ScrollView
4. Add .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) to the ScrollView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .green, .blue]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            TabView {
                ForEach(0...2, id: \.self) { index in
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(colors[index])
                }
            }
            .frame(
                width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width ,
                height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height
            )
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works in iOS 14.3! I wasn't a fan of using UIScreen.main.bounds.width/height, so after I moved out the .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) to the enclosing GeometryReader, I was able to get the full screen Tab View ignoring the safe area while setting the TabView's frame using geometry.size.width/height. Thanks!!

Comment: @andrewcar can you share how you did it with GeometryReader?

Comment: @bze12 The principle is the same as above.  Just wrap the `ScrollView` in a `GeometryReader` and replace the frame width/height with the ones from the geometry reader.  This definitely feels like a bug in `TabView` with the `PageTabViewStyle` but at least the above is a good workaround.  Was able to get a fairly complex view with top half of the view as the paged view and bottom half with other stuff working this way.

Answer (score 8):

Update in SwiftUI 3.0:

```
 TabView {
            ForEach(0...2, id: \.self) { index in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(colors[index])
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

Comment: Nice, still working on Xcode 15.2

Answer (score 6):

Wrapping TabView in a ScrollView as suggested by @kimigori [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65127817) works but causes the page dots to become scrollable. To fix them in place use a horizontal ScrollView.

[This](https://github.com/timdubbins/PageView) is a re-usable PageView that works with `ignoresSafeArea(_:edges:)`:

```
struct PageView<Content: View>: View {
    let content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                TabView {
                    content()
                }
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            }
        }
    }

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

Example:

[TestPageView gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPEWs.gif)

```
struct TestPageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        PageView {
            ForEach(0...2, id: \.self) { index in
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill([.red, .green, .blue][index])
                    Text("Page \(index + 1)")
                }
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a maximum what I've got... anyway I assume that originally it is a bug and worth submitting feedback to Apple.

Tested with Xcode 12b

[image: demo]

```
struct TestPagingStyle: View {
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .green, .blue]
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.overlay(
                GeometryReader { gp in
                    TabView {
                        ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { index in
                            Text("Hello, World \(index)")
                                .frame(width: gp.size.width, height: gp.size.height)
                                .background(colors[index])
                        }
                    }
                    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
                }
            )
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Found this by accident, so hope it works for others. Works for me on iOS15 and 16, YMMV.

Add a background color to the TabView:

```
TabView(selection: $index) {
    YourTabViewContent
    .ignoresSafeArea()
}
.background(Color.background)
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

Answer (score 3):

I worked around this annoying issue by "extending" the `TabView`'s height and "shifting" it towards the top by the same amount:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let yExtension: CGFloat = 50
        GeometryReader { g in
            TabView {
                Color.red.overlay(Text("1"))
                Color.green.overlay(Text("2"))
                Color.blue.overlay(Text("3"))
                Color.orange.overlay(Text("4"))
            }
            .frame(width: g.size.width, height: g.size.height + yExtension)
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .automatic))
            .font(Font.title.bold())
        }
        .offset(y: -yExtension)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Tested on Xcode 12.4, iOS 14.4:

[image: demo animation]

Comment: Your solution is better than what Apple delivers with its bug-prone `PageTabViewStyle`. However, your solution does not allow for rotating into Landscape. When you do so, then the page-index jumps to the beginning (and that is most likely not what the user wants). The [ScrollView-approach that kimigory showed above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65127817/3826232) is a bit better in that respect.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
.ignoresSafeArea(edges:[.top,.bottom])
```

I suppose that `TabView` can't ignore leading and trailing, which is included in `.all`. However, if you manually set `.top` and `.bottom` it works fine.

Comment: But why, please edit your answer

Comment: I suppose that tabView can't ignore leading and trailing, which includes in .all. If you manually set .top and .bottom it works fine

Comment: Hi, the purpose of my comment was to make your answer a better one. So, its best to edit it and explain it.