# Background in screens in TabView w/ PageTabViewStyle doesn't fill entire vertical space available

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, background-color, tabview

I want a TabView that uses a PageTabViewStyle with each individual screen having a different background colour that fills the entire vertical space available (i.e. extended into the safe areas).

```
TabView(selection: $selection) {
    VStack {
        Text("screen 1")
    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
     .background(Color.green)
    
    VStack {
        Text("screen 2")
    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
     .background(Color.red)

}.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
 .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
 .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```

However, it looks like this:

[image]

And after I scroll to the bottom:

[image]

The white colour can be changed if I set a background colour for the TabView itself, which would be fine if each screen used the same background colour. Is there any way for individual screens within the TabView to have a unique background colour set that fills the entire screen?

Comment: Doest this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62596307/12299030?

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't answer it, as the code doesn't result in the background color filling the entire space available, but it does look like it's the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I wouldn't suggest `GeometryReader`, but this doesn't look like intended behavior on Apple's part. The key is expanding the background modifier color to a large enough height so that you can't see the white background behind the tab.

Thank you, Asperi, for sharing the link to a similar question for inspiration:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62596307/12299030

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selection: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            TabView(selection: $selection) {
                
                VStack {
                    Text("Screen 1")
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(
                    EmptyView()
                        .frame(minHeight: 2 * geo.size.height)
                        .background(Color.green)
                )
                .tag(0)
                
                VStack {
                    Text("Screen 2")
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(
                    EmptyView()
                        .frame(minHeight: 2 * geo.size.height)
                        .background(Color.red)
                )
                .tag(1)

            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        }
    
    }
    
}
```

Using an `EmptyView` combined with a set minimum height of 2 times the current height ensures that the user can scroll up and down, reaching the bounce-back distance, and not see a white background. Put any background you'd like on this view.

You may be able to swap out `EmptyView` with whatever you'd like, but that was the first thing that came to mind. I added `.tag()` and `selection` so that `ContentView` can be ran on its own in case you'd like to experiment.